# XML native database vs. Relations DB -- PHP vs. XQuery

Tags: php, xml, database, xquery

I'm trying to develop a website in which many recipes are stored, and retrieved for the clients. I had some courses about XML and native XML-based databases, and those courses introduced the concept of native XML databases. Besides, if I remember correctly, we learned that XQuery is the most suitable programming language for working with XML. Because of the semi-structure and not so tabular nature of a recipe, I guess(please correct me if I'm wrong) that it can be best expressed in an XML file, like below :

```
<recipe>
  <ingredients>
    <name='floor' amount='500g'/>
    <name='y' amount='200g'/>
  </ingredients>
  <steps>
    <step id='1'> first prepare .....
  <steps>
</recipe>
```

I know that relational databases have their advantages and glories over other options, however it would result in so many join operations on tables in this particular case. On the other hand, native XML databases don't seem very promising to me, regarding their performance and abilities to handle a large amount of data. Besides, programming in PHP is much more simpler than XQuery, considering the huge volume of tutorials and helps on internet. 
I really don't know what to do, and that's why I came to you guys.

Comment: You wrote *"programming in PHP is much more simpler than XQuery"* and *"PHP vs. XQuery"* in title. You need to rephrase this subjective question. Also, for this kind of comparison you need to provide a full use case in order to answer.

Comment: @Alejandro: To me the comparison between PHP and XQuery is not limited only to how much they seem to be simple when programming (and by 'simple' I mean easy to debug, with access to multitudes of tutorials). In the first paragraph I actually wrote that XQuery is more suitable for XML. So each has some pros and some cons. But for the second part of your objection, I'm in agreement with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some simple determination theory without looking any strong requirements or something. 
first where is your data-source gonna be.

1. if your data is being generated through a user input screens.
2. if your data is well validated and processed by a single application( e.g) web ).
3. if your data properties and features are pretty much freezed and no new dimension to it.
4. if your data is of transaction nature.

then you can think of relation - db.

1. if your data is coming from different datasources like flat file, xml, internet screen scraping , etc etc.
2. comparatively less amount transaction
3. data properties are fluid and can have various slice / dimension to it.
4. ready to work with functional languages like XQuery or Xmllized language like XSLT

then Xml Database is the key.

Comment: Thanks very much. My data nature can be best expressed by XML. However, I'm a little afraid to use a declarative language like XQuery instead of PHP and Ajax for a big size project. What do you think?

Comment: from my understanding if your data can be best expressed by XML then u need a powerful Xml Solution like XSLT or XQUERY with that environment. you may not need a robust Xml Database if you don;t need a powerful search capabilities.  then try Zorba or MXXQuery as simple XQuery engine to query Xml Document cloud. if you some thing more defined and robust use Xml databases. on the other note functional programming picking up moment at this stage because of ease development and manageability

Answer (score 1):

Use relations DB - because it is much more faster if you get bigger amout of records , and it is simplier to create. 
( for your example it is 3 tables - one with recipes, another with ingredients and the last one with steps. Alternative is to create table with all known ingredients and use association - eg. table with ID of recipe, ID of ingredient and amount )

Comment: Doesn't it cause millions of joins between tables? The alternative, XML-based database, would have much less join operations, right?

Comment: XML-based DB will not have JOINS, BUT - MySQL, MSSQL and others can use Views - so if you are scared about writing joins - use views ( or stored query ) - it will make output pretty. In your example JOIN isn't literally needed ( only if you will use association )

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a point here, so please let me know:  standing queries (aka logical views) are actually joins on the table, unless you are talking about physical views, in which the whole view is stored physically on the disk. Second, I didn't get why you said that in my case, I wouldn't need JOIN. what else could we do when we want to retrieve a recipe with all its ingredients and steps?

Comment: I don't know what you don't like about JOINs. In this case if i want to write out one recipe i will not use JOINs, because they are creted for one-to-one fetching ( eg. recipe-author ). If we need to fetch one to many - process it on PHP level ( first query - fetch recipe, second ... - fetch ingredients, steps etc. using WHERE IDRecipe = ... ) - if you need example , just write

Comment: The thing about the JOIN that I'm really afraid of is the burden they put on the server side. Suppose the table of recipes and the table of ingredients has 2000 and 1000 entries, respectively. As their relationship is M-N (one recipe includes ingredients and each ingredient can be included in many recipes), we need to create another table, say with 20000 entries. I really don't know what happens in reality, so I'm asking: do tens of queries per second for retrieving the whole recipe info to the server cause it to become slow, due to JOIN between recipe table, M-N table and ingredient table?

Comment: In reality - MySQL and MSSQL are hardly optimised to handle this swiftly ( be sure to use Indexes or Foreign Keys correctly ) - from my expirience - server have no problem to handle hundred of queries with much more data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're thinking that you have to choose one or the other here. That isn't the case, XQuery isn't really setup to be a complete web scripting environment, it's a replacement to SQL not PHP. Therefore you can certainly use PHP to do the web focused parts of the site such as user logins (which could also be in a relational DB) then use XQUery just for your recipe querying layer.

Some XML databases such as MarkLogic can also do all the web logic side of the equation but they don't offer the same richness of libraries yet, so I would certainly recommend PHP or something like that for the web tier.

Comment: Well, XQuery is a yet growing replacement for XQuery(maybe not complete replacement, as you said), and compared to PHP, which has a lot of framework to enhance web development, XQuery has also some packages to improve the functionality and scalability in terms of different layer of server side, such as Sausalito (28msec.com). But I have to admit that I'm in agreement with you on this issue that Using merely XQuery in the development process may pose a lot of problem and difficulties.